# Postname permalinks not working – all pages send to homepage

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, wpml

I have WordPress installed in a subfolder of my domain. I want to keep it there, so that it is accessible only through http://www.example.com/mywordpress.

I have an issue with permalinks. If I use postname permalinks, all my pages (with different templates applied) redirect to the homepage, while my archives (including custom post type archives and singles) are displaying correctly. If I use custom structure permalinks and I prepend anything to the postname – for example /test/%postname%/ – all pages display correctly while custom post type archives and singles display a 404 error.
This happens whenever I refresh permalinks and also after replacing .htaccess with one from a brand new WP install.

The odd thing is also how the permalinks are displaying in the browser url field:

**if I use /%postname%/**

- pages (not working) display as
  http://www.example.com/mywordpress/postname – they all display the
  homepage contents
- CPT archives+singles (working) display as
  http://www.example.com/mywordpress/postname

**if I use /test/%postname%/**

- pages (working) display as
  http://www.example.com/mywordpress/postname – so without the
  prepended text!
- CPT archives+singles (not working) display as
  http://www.example.com/mywordpress/test/postname – displaying a 404
  error

My custom post types have slugs translated to different languages with WPML. I thought that might cause the issue, however I tried to deactivate all plugins included WPML and still no luck.

Does anyone know what might cause that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was using reserved terms as custom taxonomy slugs (https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms). By changing them to something else everything started working normally again!